# Regex help. Extract number from string after a forward slash

Tags: java, regex

I have a file path that looks like this:

```
"lab_4_input_files/asc50.dat"
"lab_4_input_files/asc500.dat"
"lab_4_input_files/asc500-1.dat"
```

and I want to extract the 50, 500, 499. IS there a way to do this with regex and logic?

Currently my regex is `fileName.replaceAll("\\D+","")` but it returns me:

```
450
4500
45001
```

the 4 from the folder name cannot be in the end result and 500-1 needs to be calculated. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Regex can't actually perform mathematical expressions. However JavaScript can! And there is a JavaScript engine built right into the JDK.

Although this is a bit of a hack, this will get you the results you wanted. Note that initializing an entire JavaScript engine will be resource heavy, but it will make executing a String math expression much easier.

```
    ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    // Regex to match any character you'd typically find in a simple mathematical expression after "asc"
    String regex = "(?<=asc)[0-9+\\-\\*\\\\\\(\\) ]+";

    // Your input data
    String line = "lab_4_input_files/asc500-1.dat";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String expression = matcher.group();
        try {
            int extractedNumber = (Integer) engine.eval(expression);
            System.out.println(extractedNumber);
        } catch (ScriptException exception) {
            // Handle invalid expression
        }
    } else {
        // Handle no regex match
    }
```